# Discrete time system - phase response

Tags: control-theory, z-transform

I have a question about a discrete time filter. All I have is the pole-zero plot and I have to calculate the impulse, phase and magnitude response. To make this a proper fraction I used polynomial division:

$$H(z) = \frac{z-0.5}{z+0.5}= 1-\frac{1}{z+0.5}$$

Now I bracket out the z, so I can use the z-Transform
$$H(z) = 1-z^{-1} \cdot \frac{1}{1+0.5*z^{-1}}$$

When I use the transformation, I get the impulse response $h[n]= \delta[n] - (0.5)^{n} \cdot u[n-1]$ Is this correct?

For the phase response I set $e^{j\omega}$ into $H(z)$:

$$H(e^{j\omega}) = 1-\frac{1}{e^{j\omega }+ 0.5}$$

How can I get $|H(e^{j \omega})|$?

Comment: I don't know if what you've already done is correct, but the last step is easy: $1-\frac{1}{e^{j \omega} + 0.5} = \frac{e^{j \omega} - 0.5}{e^{j \omega} + 0.5}$. Now use Euler's identity and take the quotient of the two moduli; you should get $\frac{\sqrt{(\cos(\omega)-0.5)^2+\sin(\omega)^2}}{\sqrt{(\cos(\omega)+0.5)^2 + \sin(\omega)^2}}$. This does simplify a bit, but if you need to do that, it's not complicated (you just need $\cos^2+\sin^2=1$).

Comment: Thanks! I did something similar before, but used the euler's identity too early and got a huge expression. Maybe it was correct, but this is way was better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write

$$ \frac{Y(z)}{U(z)} = \frac{1 - 0.5 z^{-1}}{1 + 0.5 z^{-1}} $$

to obtain the difference equation

$$ h[n] = -0.5 h[n-1] + \delta[n] - 0.5 \delta[n-1] $$

for the impulse response. Assuming $h[-1] = 0$ you can write a few values and figure out the general rule for impulse response instead of calculating the convolution. So,

$$h[0] = 1, h[1] = -1, h[2] = 0.5, h[3] = -(0.5)^2, h[4] = (0.5)^3, \dots$$

The general rule is

$$ h[n] = \delta[n] - (-0.5)^{n-1} u[n-1] $$

where $u$ is the step function.

For the phase response you can use the Euler's identity as @Ian stated in the comments.